# Irreducible components of certain (potentially non-Noetherian) spectrum

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\Bbbk$ be an algebraically closed field (not necessarily characteristic zero), and let $R$ be a finitely generated $\Bbbk$-algebra.  Let $S\subseteq R$ be a $\Bbbk$-subalgebra, and let $X=\operatorname{Spec}S$.

Of course $S$ need not be finitely generated---but my question is, does $X$ still have irreducible components?  Can we write $X=X_1\cup \dots \cup X_r$ such that each $X_i$ is irreducible?

Even simpler question: is it known whether $X$ must be a Noetherian topological space?  I'm guessing the answer is no, since I can't find such a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For irreducible components: if $\varphi : A \to B$ is any ring map, then every minimal prime of $\ker \varphi$ in $A$ is the contraction of a minimal prime of $B$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/935987) for proof). In particular, any subring of a ring with finitely many minimal primes also has finitely many minimal primes.

Comment: The phrasing in the first sentence has a $\ker$ in it which seems like it might not need to be there? Or am I misreading something?

Comment: @KReiser I meant $\ker \varphi$ as an ideal in $A$ (and its minimal primes)

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thank you!  Way simpler than I thought.